# Text detection/recognition using Opencv 3.0.0

Tags: c++, opencv3.0

- I want to detect/recognition text using Opencv 3.0.0 from image.
- But i can't find any tect detection module in it.But if i do google then i found that opencv 3.0.0 gives text detection support.
- Can any body tell me what i am missing here.

Comment: https://github.com/Itseez/opencv_contrib/blob/master/modules/text/samples/textdetection.cpp

Comment: @Miki : So this is seperate module and i have to build it with opencv, right?

Comment: yes, you need to recompile OpenCV with contrib modules

Comment: @Miki : Ok.Got it.Thanks!!!

Comment: @Miki : can you please tell me commant to build this module with opencv.

Comment: https://github.com/Itseez/opencv_contrib